How do I make alterations to this shapefile in python with geopandas or cartopy?
How do I add light grey state lines, change the background to white, and change certain areas to certain colors? This is from the EPA Level2 ecoregion map. I'd like to color each ecoregion a separate color.

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the shapefile
shapefile_path = "/home/student/tsjohnson/NA_CEC_Eco_Level2.shx"
level2 = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

# Create the plot
ax = level2.plot(edgecolor='black', figsize=(10, 8))

# Set axis limits
ax.set_xlim([-2.25E6,-1E6])
ax.set_ylim([-1E6, 0.6E6])

# Show the plot
plt.show()

I tried this and it stretched the image and didnt add anything.
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the shapefile
shapefile_path = "/home/student/tsjohnson/NA_CEC_Eco_Level2.shx"
level2 = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

# Create the plot with white background
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
level2.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor='black')
# Set axis limits
ax.set_xlim([-2.25E6, -1E6])
ax.set_ylim([-1E6, 0.5E6])
ax.set_facecolor('white')
us_states = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
states = us_states[us_states['continent'] == 'North America']  # Filter for North American states

states.boundary.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color='black')

plt.show()


To be able to change certain areas to certain colors, you must be able to identify and grab that areas first. And you can specify it's facecolor to the desired color,  i.e. fc="white"  as an option in the plot statement.

I suggest you manually specify each color to get them right. I chose  colors similar to the ones on this map
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = r"C:\Users\bera\Downloads\na_cec_eco_l2\NA_CEC_Eco_Level2.shp"
df = gpd.read_file(f)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10,10))

colormap = {"MARINE WEST COAST FOREST":"lightseagreen",
            "WESTERN CORDILLERA":"limegreen",
            "COLD DESERTS":"khaki",
            "MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA":"lightgreen",
            "WARM DESERTS":"gold",
            "UPPER GILA MOUNTAINS":"#a4f0dd"}
df["color"] = df["NA_L2NAME"].map(colormap).fillna("grey")

states = gpd.read_file(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/refs/heads/master/data/geojson/us-states.json")
states = states.to_crs(df.crs)

ax.set_xlim([-2.25E6,-1E6])
ax.set_ylim([-1E6, 0.6E6])
ax.set_axis_off()

df.plot(figsize=(10,10), ax=ax, color=df.color, zorder=1)
df.boundary.plot(ax=ax, color="olive", zorder=2, linewidth=1)
states.boundary.plot(ax=ax, zorder=2, color="black", 
                     linewidth=3)


